# How to programmatically select multiple sheets and copy to the same workbook at the same time in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm looking for some advices.

I'm sorry, I don't know how to make it clarify in text, so, I will show you what I need to achieve via Excel instead.

1. Select multiple sheet by Ctrl+Left click (To make Sheet1, Sheet2 active)

[image]

2. Right click > Move or Copy... > select (move to end) > check "Creat a copy" > Ok

[image]

3. Result

[image]

I would like to know 2 things

1. How to select multiple sheets
2. How to copy selected sheets to the same workbook in 1 shot

The reason why I want to copy both in 1 shot because I put formula in Sheet1 in cell A1 which is "=Sheet2!A1". If I copy it one by one the formula won't change but If I select both sheets and copy at the same time, the formula will change to "=Sheet2(2)!A1" automatically << This is what I intend to do.

Which excel interop command should I use to achieve this result ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
            var MyApp = new Excel.Application();
            MyApp.Visible = false;
            var MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(path);

            Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1];
            sheet.Copy(MyBook.Sheets[MyBook.Sheets.Count]);

            sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[2];
            sheet.Copy(MyBook.Sheets[MyBook.Sheets.Count]);

            MyBook.Save();
```

Comment: I'm sorry that my question wasn't clear enough. The reason why I want to copy both in 1 shot because I put formula in Sheet1 in cell A1 which is "=Sheet2!A1". If I copy it 1 by 1 the formula won't change but If I select both sheets and copy at the same time, the formula will change to "=Sheet2(2)!A1" automatically. So, this is what I want to archive.